# make output redirection

Tags: bash, macos

I want to redirect the output and error stream of make command to file.

The following command

```
make 1>&2 ~/tmp/build.log
```

throws the following error

```
make: Nothing to be done for `/Users/m/tmp/build.log'.
```

EDIT:-

Tried

```
make 2>&1 ~/tmp/build.log
```

and

```
make ~/tmp/build.log 2>&1
```

which gave the same above error message.

I am using mac-leopard os

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Tietos-iMac-2:qt-build ptools$ sh --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Answer (score 7):

Should be

```
make 2>&1 > ~/tmp/build.log
```

Comment: @arnaud576875: <ahem>good catch (silly ````````` padding requirements, eh)

Comment: @Talespin_Kit: could you be more specific? What did it say now? Can you tell us what shell you are using?

Comment: @sehe: using bash shell **$ echo $0 -bash**. I have edited the question to add the info on the version of bash. Please look in the question. I thought initially the solution you have provided works, but i found warning messages printed on the terminal. I think the error stream is not redirected to file.

Comment: That's surprising. You might look at (sub)makefiles explicitely redirecting to /dev/tty e.g. I don't have any other clues right now

Comment: I am compiling qt sources on mac. I have used the command **find . -name Makefile -exec grep '/dev/tty' {} \;** to find any Makefiles containing the string '/dev/tty' but the search returned none.

Comment: @Talespin_Kit: You did notice that extra `>` you have to use, right ?

Comment: @DarkD yes i did. After using the extra `>` it works except the warning messages are printed to the console.

Comment: Yes, warnings when compiling qt go to the console, even when `2>&1` done properly! Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

you can also just do:

```
make &> build.log
```

"&>" means send stdout and stderr to this file