# How do we save logs while building the code?

Tags: c, linux, logging

I am building code in C using make , how would I save build logs ?

Comment: redirect output to a file maybe?? what is producing the build logs?

Answer (score 7):

If you both want to save the log and see it on the console, you could use the [`tee`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee) command:

```
make 2>&1 | tee build.log
```

The `2>&1` part is telling the shell to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`.

Comment: @user1737057 By default `tee` recreates (i.e. overwrites) the file. Are you really sure it's old content? Are you looking in an old file?

Answer (score 2):

Typically the most interesting output (compiler warnings and errors) goes to stderr. In bash:

```
$ make 2> out
```

Then inspect the file nameed `out`. The `2>` is a [Bash output redirection operator](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirecting-Output).

Answer (score 2):

Shell output redirection will help you here.

```
make 2>&1 > output.log
```

See: [make output redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119875/make-output-redirection)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the output of make then use:

```
make 1>std.out 2> err.out
```

The 1 means the standardoutput and 2 the erroroutput

Answer (score 1):

If you use standard make, I assume you do it through a terminal, so you would only have to do : `make >> mylogfile.log`.
For more tricks about I/O redirection, take a look [here](http://www.linuxsa.org.au/tips/io-redirection.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
make 2>&1 > output.log
```

This will help you

Answer (score 0):

In addition to redirection proposed by another answers, consider the [script](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script) utility which writes the complete log of your interaction with a shell and its children or with another program: both input and output.

Sometimes you have to intervene during make, fix something in place when it fails, restart again. When a thing like that is done in a hurry, it's beneficial to have a protocol of what you've done *without having to think of logging or recording when you do it*.